# blocking an ip in ip tables

Tags: mysql, linux, iptables

blocking mysql access for an ip
I have unscrupulous incoming connections to my mysql database server and I want to block it, so I add the following line in /etc/sysconfig/iptables and restarted it

```
    -A INPUT -s 206.xxx.xx.xx -j DROP
```

but the ip connection is still able to access my mysql database server and perform queries. why? how do I effectively block it?

Comment: Blocking access at the packet level is one thing, but how can this 'unscrupulous' machine log in to your database? Change your passwords immediately. All of them.

Comment: @Mike W: I already changed mysql database password.. can root password be compromised also?

Comment: If your security was lax enough to allow unauthorised connections to your database anything is possible. Don't be complacent. Do harden your server against this sort of intrusion again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your using with Firewalls (IPTABLES) Please specify the Port in which Mysql server is listening on.

The following rule will provide specific network only will be listening on
Only the 192.168.100.0/24 network people can access your mysql. Here i have specified the default mysql port 3306

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -s 192.168.100.0/24 --dport 3306 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

**To DROP IP Address**

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -s 206.xxx.xx.xx --dport 3306 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j DROP
```

Comment: can I block all ports access for an ip or an ip block?

Comment: @user3324120 : Yes, You can. If you are blocking IPAddress in the Local Environment is good. But that is going to be an Foolish idea, when you are deploying in Internet. Because, Hacker can pick up any IP (By IP Spoofing). So you cant filter all the IP ( There are chances your clients could get filtered) which it was attacked your server.